# Lock the computer with pynput

Tags: python

I'm trying to lock the computer with pynput by pressing the winkey(tried it with both left and right) and 'l' but for some reason but for some reason it isn't working while pressing winkey and 'r' do bring the run menu for example

Comment: Hello welcome to SO, can we see a snippet of the code you are using?

Comment: Sorry for the no spaceline im on mobile and it doesn't allow me to press enter `keyboard = Controller() keyboard.press(Key.cmd_l) keyboard.press('l')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to lock your computer or do you want to use pynput?

If you just want to lock your computer, you could use

```
import os
os.system('rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation')
```